# How to write an unchangeable class in c#?

Tags: c#, readonly

I am writing a class with some functions and properties and texts in it.

I want that everyone who use my class can see the functions and texts and properties but could not change them.

How to do this first?

And in advanced I want that they can add some other functions and texts and properties to it, but could not change the existing ones that I wrote.

And how to do this next?

**Update**

There is a class that contains CRUD functions. Its created by a code generator that I have written. Now the people can add the created class and use its functions to do CRUD functions. I don't want to make it as a dll file as far as possible and I don't want to make the whole class readonly as far as possible again. I just want that when the people include the created class in their projects, they can add another function to it but they can not change or remove the functions which is generated with the code generator.

Comment: Look at the Access Modifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: What are texts? What is _"not change them"_, do you mean change the value of properties or do you mean overriding properties and methods?

Comment: This all depends on how you intend on distributing the code? If you are providing it as a DLL then users can't change your code regardless but can of course derive from existing classes (if you allow).

Comment: Show what code you have now. Maybe people will have some helpful comments for you based on that. We don't have enough information to write the class for you.

Comment: This generally is not a problem that is not entirely solvable with code in the first place. It's an 'How to use this class' problem. But anyway: Just write a normal class without any virtuals and mark it with the 'sealed' keyword - and you are as close as you can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want that when the people include the created class in their projects, they can add another function to it but they can not change or remove the functions which is generated with the code generator

Unfortunately you can't do this, once you distribute code a developer has complete control over it. It's generally not recommended to modify generated code anyway, however, it can actually work to your advantage if your code contains a bug or is not compatible and needs to be tweaked.

The best approach would be to make your generated code class `partial` which makes it much easier to extend e.g.

```
namespace My.Generated.Code
{
    public partial class GeneratedClass
    {
        ...
    }
}
...

namespace Some.Other.Project
{
    using My.Generated.Code;

    public partial class GeneratedClass
    {
        public string NewProperty { get; set; }

        public void NewMethod()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As long as you don't make any of the properties in your generated class `virtual` then developers can add new behaviour/properties but can't modify existing.

Comment: Thank you very much but can I ask a question based on your experience and not related to programming?
How Can I convince a boss that don't know programming and just have heard that code generator is a good thing and force a lot to make one when all of us know its not recommended???

Comment: @HamidReza it's not considered a *bad* idea to write a code generator, lots of applications/tools have & use them (VS especially). I guess the question is more do you actually need one? You would need to convince your boss on the reasons why you *don't* need one, that's not really something I can help you with because I have no idea about your application and it's purpose.

Comment: Yes but the thing that he wants is a code generator that generates the models and repository layer and make their class library as a dll file and no one can change them. It means after completing the code generator project our other projects would have just a dll in their repository and model and application class library and nothing else. His idea is a real weak one from every view but...

Comment: @HamidReza it sounds like you don't need a code generator at all then... In fact, it sounds as though your boss is confusing a *re-usable* library with a code generator (which builds code *every* time).

Comment: You exactly hit the target I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could compile your class as .dll, so other user can add it to his project and cannot to change it. Also he could make inheritance and add his own methods without changing the parent class.

Comment: See the OP's update, they don't want to provide it as a DLL - it's an auto-generated class.

Answer (score 0):

you can set this properties and methods as `sealed` it really depends on your needs.

have some time to read about **C# modifiers**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tcf2h8w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make your class as a base class or create an Interface/Abstract class and let other inherit it , they can add function/property/method but all things you did is as is unless it is virtual